# Sibling vs Parent/Child relationship detection using whole-genome sequence data

Tags: wgs, plink

I am analyzing a family-based whole-genome sequence (WGS) dataset.  My identity-by-descent(IBD) analysis shows they share about 50% of their DNA. I think my pedigree structure may have gotten mixed up though and I want to see if one individual is the mother or the sister of a male individual.  Is there anyway to do this either with Plink or [KING](http://people.virginia.edu/~wc9c/KING/manual.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With at least three samples, you can determine this by looking at the IBS0 output column (from either plink2 --make-king-table or KING): if the relationship in question has a very low IBS0 value compared to the other pairs, that's parent-child.  You can try to do the same thing with only two samples, but with no other IBS0 values to compare against it's easier to misjudge.